# Creating a rvest::html_session to a servr::httd http server

Tags: r, session, rvest, servr

I'm working on a project that requires accessing webpages and I do this via
`rvest::html_session()`.  For documentation and training I would like to set
up a reproducible example and have considered the following.

1. Use `servr::httd(system.file("egwebsite", package = "<pkgname>"), daemon =
   TRUE, browser = FALSE)` to set up a  simple HTTP server
2. Use `rvest::html_session("http://127.0.0.1:4321")` to set up the html
   session.

However, the following simple example behaves differently on Linux (Debian 9)
and Windows 10.  (I do not have easy access to OSx and have not tested on
that OS).

```
# On Windows
servr::httd(daemon = TRUE, browser = FALSE, port = 4321) 
## Serving the directory /home/dewittpe/so/my-servr-question at http://127.0.0.1:4321
## To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop("94019719908480") or restart your R session

R.utils::withTimeout(
                    {
                      s <- rvest::html_session("http://127.0.0.1:4321")
                    },
                    timeout = 3,
                    onTimeout = "error") 

s 
## <session> http://127.0.0.1:4321/
##   Status: 200
##   Type:   text/html
##   Size:   2352
servr::daemon_stop()
```

However, on my Linux box (Debian 9) I get the following

```
servr::httd(daemon = TRUE, browser = FALSE, port = 4321) 
## Serving the directory /home/dewittpe/so/my-servr-question at http://127.0.0.1:4321
## To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop("94019719908480") or restart your R session

R.utils::withTimeout(
                    {
                      s <- rvest::html_session("http://127.0.0.1:4321")
                    },
                    timeout = 3,
                    onTimeout = "error") 
## Error: reached elapsed time limit
## Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
##   Operation was aborted by an application callback
```

That is, I am unable to create a `html_session` in the same R interactive
session that spawned the http server.  If, however, I start a second R
session while the leaving the initial session running, I am able to create
the `html_session` without error.

What can I do so that I can create an `html_session` based on a `servr::httd`
HTTP server within the same R session on Linux?

**Edit 1**

If I add `httr::verbose()` to the `html_session` call I get the following when the session is created successfully.  When the process hangs and fails to create the session the output stops on the last `->` and none of the lines with `<-` are shown.

```
> s <- html_session("http://127.0.0.1:4321", httr::verbose())
-> GET / HTTP/1.1
-> Host: 127.0.0.1:4321
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.52.1 r-curl/3.1 httr/1.3.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
->
<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Content-Type: text/html
<- Content-Length: 61303
<-
```

Comment: `servr` tag typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, run `servr::httd` in a subprocess.  This solution requires the [subprocess](https://cran.r-project.org/package=subprocess) package.

First, a helper function `R_binary` will return the file path for the R binary on Windows or unix based OS.

```
R_binary <- function () {
  R_exe <- ifelse (tolower(.Platform$OS.type) == "windows", "R.exe", "R")
  return(file.path(R.home("bin"), R_exe))
}
```

Next, start R vanilla as a subprocess.

```
subR <- subprocess::spawn_process(R_binary(), c("--vanilla"))
```

Then start the HTTP server in the subprocess

```
subprocess::process_write(subR, 'servr::httd(".", browser = FALSE, port = 4321)\n')
## [1] 47
subprocess::process_read(subR)$stderr
## [1] "Serving the directory /home/dewittpe/so/my-servr-question at http://127.0.0.1:4321"
```

A quick test to show that there is communication between the active R session and the HTTP server:

```
session <- rvest::html_session("http://127.0.0.1:4321")
session
## <session> http://127.0.0.1:4321/
##   Status: 200
##   Type:   text/html
##   Size:   1054
```

And finally, kill the subprocess

```
subprocess::process_kill(subR)
```